# RSiteSearch doesn't work with multiword queries

Tags: r

I'm new to programming in R and I'm following the book ["Learning R" by Richard Cotton](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449357105). When I tried out the search function RSiteSearch however, the spaces in the query is replaced by a '+' instead. For example, `"Naive Bayes"` would become `"Naive+Bayes"` which caused the search engine to find 0 results. Can anyone help me with this? I have already tried enclosing the words in braces like this: `"{Naive Bayes}"` as the examples in the book and on the internet shows but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: for what it's worth, `sos::findFn("{naive Bayes}")` does work (although it doesn't do exactly the same as RSiteSearch)

Comment: Did you send an erratum to the author? Also, for all those of us who don't have the book, can you reference which chapter and page it's on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, it isnt working as stated in the documentation. If you look at the source code for the function it looks like there is a bug.

```
function (string, restrict = c("functions", "vignettes", "views"), 
  format = c("normal", "short"), sortby = c("score", "date:late", 
    "date:early", "subject", "subject:descending", "from", 
    "from:descending", "size", "size:descending"), matchesPerPage = 20) 
{
  string <- paste0("http://search.r-project.org/cgi-bin/namazu.cgi?query=", 
    URLencode(gsub(" ", "+", string), reserved = TRUE))
  mpp <- paste0("max=", matchesPerPage)
  format <- paste0("result=", match.arg(format))
  restrictVALS <- c("functions", "vignettes", "views")
  restr <- match.arg(restrict, choices = restrictVALS, several.ok = TRUE)
  restr <- paste(paste0("idxname=", restr), collapse = "&")
  sortby <- match.arg(sortby)
  sortby <- paste0("sort=", switch(sortby, score = , `date:late` = , 
    `date:early` = sortby, subject = "field:subject:ascending", 
    `subject:descending` = "field:subject:descending", from = "field:from:ascending", 
    `from:descending` = "field:from:descending", size = "field:size:ascending", 
    `size:descending` = "field:size:descending"))
  qstring <- paste(string, mpp, format, sortby, restr, sep = "&")
  browseURL(qstring)
  cat(gettextf("A search query has been submitted to %s", 
    "http://search.r-project.org"), "\n", sep = "")
  cat(gettext("The results page should open in your browser shortly\n"))
  invisible(qstring)
}
```

It looks like there is an issue with `URLencode(gsub(" ", "+", string), reserved = TRUE)`. This adds the `+` but then escapes the sign in the query which we don't want.

I also don't see any code for handling the braces in the source code which seems very strange. I changes the function here which seems to work as written in the documentation.

```
new_search = function (string, restrict = c("functions", "vignettes", "views"), 
          format = c("normal", "short"), sortby = c("score", "date:late", 
                                                    "date:early", "subject", "subject:descending", "from", 
                                                    "from:descending", "size", "size:descending"), matchesPerPage = 20) 
{

  if(grepl("[{}]",string)){
    string = gsub("[{}]","",string)
    reserved <- TRUE
  }else{
    reserved <- FALSE
  }

  string <- paste0("http://search.r-project.org/cgi-bin/namazu.cgi?query=", 
                   URLencode(string, reserved = reserved))

  mpp <- paste0("max=", matchesPerPage)
  format <- paste0("result=", match.arg(format))
  restrictVALS <- c("functions", "vignettes", "views")
  restr <- match.arg(restrict, choices = restrictVALS, several.ok = TRUE)
  restr <- paste(paste0("idxname=", restr), collapse = "&")
  sortby <- match.arg(sortby)
  sortby <- paste0("sort=", switch(sortby, score = , `date:late` = , 
                                   `date:early` = sortby, subject = "field:subject:ascending", 
                                   `subject:descending` = "field:subject:descending", from = "field:from:ascending", 
                                   `from:descending` = "field:from:descending", size = "field:size:ascending", 
                                   `size:descending` = "field:size:descending"))
  qstring <- paste(string, mpp, format, sortby, restr, sep = "&")
  browseURL(qstring)
  cat(gettextf("A search query has been submitted to %s", 
               "http://search.r-project.org"), "\n", sep = "")
  cat(gettext("The results page should open in your browser shortly\n"))
  invisible(qstring)
}
```

This does seem very odd. If we are doing something wrong here please let us know and i'll take the answer down. If this highlights a bug we need to do something about it.